# ¿Como obtengo los valores que se encuentran dentro de un objeto con c#?

Tags: c#, objeto

como obtengo los datos que se encuentran dentro de un objeto.
Inserto una imagen para que se den una idea de lo que necesito. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo estoy obteniendo el objeto en general, pero necesito descomponer el objeto y tomar los registros que se encuentran en dicho objeto para agregarlos en una lista, dato por dato.

Comment: trata de hacer una clase con todas las propiedades, no utilices object y de esa forma Si deserializas

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude tener acceso.